# I'll have finished VS I'll be finished

Tags: verb-forms

Have the two sentences below the same meaning?

> I'll have finished my work by tomorrow.
>
> I'll be finished with my work by tomorrow.

I also came across "**I'll be finished by tomorrow**", it has the same meaning of those sentences above in the context, but which makes me think as if I were chased by, say, a Terminator :-)
Could you please explain it to me?

Comment: In *"I'll have finished ..."*, *finished* is a verb. In *"I'll be finished ..."*, *finished* is an adjective, and it can be ambiguous because it can mean either "at the end of a task" or "doomed". However, when being used in *"I'll be finished with my work by tomorrow,"* the meaning of *finished* is clear and the sentence means roughly the same as *I'll have finished my work by tomorrow,"* as you seem to already know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most contexts, they say essentially the same thing: **The work will be finished tomorrow**.

You can say it either way because there is often more than one way to express the completion of a task:

- You can be done working on a task
- The task can be complete

In cases where one individual is working on a task, both of these become true at the same time.

You can change the generic "my work" with a more concrete phrase to see how this works (each sentence in the pair is grammatical and acceptable):

> I'll have finished the new roof by tomorrow.
> I'll be finished with the new roof by tomorrow.
>
> I'll have finished designing the interface by tomorrow.
> I'll be finished with the interface design by tomorrow.
>
> I'll have finished stripping the paint by tomorrow.
> I'll be finished with the paint stripping by tomorrow.
>
> I'll have finished doing my taxes by tomorrow.
> I'll be finished with my taxes by tomorrow.

All of these assume that the task is being completed by a single individual. Other circumstances may apply:

> I'll be finished with the wiring on the Simpson house tomorrow. *Then I'll start working on the Flanders house, while the rest of the crew will finish the wiring at the Simpson house*.

In that last example, me being done with the task does **not** mean the task is complete – it simply means I am no longer contributing to the project.